# how to bind part of a string in zk while using mvvm model

Tags: java, mvvm, label, zk, zul

So, let us say we want to do some things like this:

```
<label zclass="class1 class2 @load(vm.class)" />
```

How to do this in ZK?

the above code render `zclass` as `class1 class2 @load(vm.class)`. But we want to execute `@load`?

Comment: What is You want to do here can u explain a bit more its hard to guess what you want to ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cat`-like methods from the `core` taglib to concatenate strings. Something like this:

```js
<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/dsp/web/core" prefix="c"?>
...
<label zclass="@load(c:cat('class1 class2 ', vm.class))" />
```

For more details on `core` methods see [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML%20Reference/EL%20Expressions/Core%20Methods)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, i went with an AbstractViewModel that contains all those "technical" methods i would like to use in my Zul.

Then i make every of my Viewmodel extends this abstractViewModel

```
public class AbstractTechnicalViewModel {

    /** @see java.text.MessageFormat#format(String, Object...) */
    public String format(final String pPattern, final Object... pParams) {
        return MessageFormat.format(pPattern, pParams);
    }

    /** @see org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#concatenate(Object[]) */
    public String concat(final Object... pParams) {
        return StringUtils.join(pParams);
    }
}
```

And then in my zul

```
tooltiptext="${vm.format(labels.my.label, param1)}"
```

Regards